# Error getting @reference entity with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the **Exec** entity:

```java
@Entity("Exec")
public class Exec {
  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  private long initDate;
  private long endDate;
  public enum statuses {
    SUCCESS, FAIL, PARTIAL
  }
  private statuses status;
  @Reference(idOnly = true, ignoreMissing = true, lazy = false)
  Analysis analysis;
  @Reference(idOnly = true, ignoreMissing = true, lazy = true)
  Set<Conclusion> conclusions = new HashSet<Conclusion>();
  // getters and setters
```

which has a reference to the **Conclusion** entity:

```java
@Entity("Conclusion")
public class Conclusion {
  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  private Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  private long initDate;
  private long endDate;
  public enum statuses {
    SUCCESS, 
    FAILURE
  }
  private statuses status; 
  private String errorMessage;
  private String stackTrace;
  Set<Map<String, Object>> data = new HashSet<Map<String, Object>>();
```

In the debugger, if I try to get the conclusions

```java
Set<Conclusions> conclusions = mongoWrapper.getDataStore().createQuery(Exec.class).asList().get(0).getConclusions()
```

I get the following message:

```
com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.
```

If I try to access the object, for example, doing the following:

```
conclusions.toArray()
```

it throws a RuntimeException, examining the stack trace:

```
org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Embedded element isn't a DBObject! How can it be that is a class java.lang.String
```

I tried changing a bunch of stuff, nothing really worked. Any ideas of what is the matter of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

using concrete AnalysisConclusion in a set of Conclusion.
remember that annotation are not inherited, then mark AnalysisConclusion with @Entity

Comment: my mistake, I simpliflied the name of the class from AnalysisConclusion to Conclusion (and the other classes) for readability, I've corrected the snippet. There are no other classes involved, just Exec and Conclusion.

Comment: For the record `@Entity` is marked up with `@Inherited`.

Comment: can you paste an example of the data you're saving in to these objects?  I'll try to recreate that error locally.